# How to draw a name in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have names in my database and I want to draw a name for a contest.

Anyone have an idea for that ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Table structure? What have you tried? Etc.?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE num_value >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(num_value) FROM table) LIMIT 1
```

This works in constant time, regardless of the table size, if num_value is indexed. One caveat: this assumes that num_value is equally distributed in the range 0..MAX(num_value). If your dataset strongly deviates from this assumption, you will get skewed results (some rows will appear more often than others).

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed ! I tried to do that in pure php, but your idea is much better !

Answer (score 2):

A query like this could work

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```